# Magento2 controller redirecting to blank page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, controllers

Magento2 after executing the file controller redirecting to a blank page. can anyone please help me?

```
$this->_view->loadLayout();
       $this->_view->renderLayout();
```

**routes.xml**

```
<router id="standard">
    <route id="promotion" frontName="promotion">
      <module name="Company_Promotion"/>
    </route>
  </router>
```

**layout**

```
<referenceContainer name="content">           
            <block class="Company\Promotion\Block\Promotion" name="coupon_generate" template="Company_Promotion::products.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

Thanks.

Comment: please add your routes.xml and layout file in question

Comment: added the files

Comment: what is layout file name and your controller name

Comment: You need to return `$this->_pageFactory->create();` this i think..pls refer https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-controllers-magento-2.html

Comment: What's the name of the layout?

Comment: company_index_post

Comment: thanks @Ranganathan
It working

Comment: you're welcome ...:-)

Comment: @Ranganathan, please feel free to post your answer at here.

Comment: @AmitBera okie....

Answer (score 1):

etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="promotion" frontName="promotion">
            <module name="Company_Promotion" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Promotion\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

view/frontend/layout/promotion_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <head>
        <title>Titlename</title>
    </head> 

    <body>


        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Company\Promotion\Block\Index\Sidebar" name="promotion_index_sidebar" before="-" template="Company_Promotion::promotion_index_sidebar.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Company\Promotion\Block\Index\Index" name="promotion_index_index" template="Company_Promotion::promotion_index_index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>


    </body>
</page>
```

Block/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Company\Promotion\Block\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = []) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

view/frontend/templates/promotion_index_index.phtml

```
You content goes here
```